# What could be causing feature1 branch's commits to show up in feature2 branch logs?

Tags: git, version-control

The commit history from another feature branch keeps on showing up in a new feature branch?  Why is this?

The only thing I can think of is that I need to checkout `master` between checking out a new feature branch, but I seriously doubt that's actually necessary.

The following happens:

`git log: Rebuilt for deployment`

```
git status
  On branch john-cleanup
  Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

  deleted:    some-file.jsx
```

`git commit -m "Remove some-file"`

```
git log

Remove some-file
last-feature-branch-commit
another-different-feature-branch-commit
...
```

Comment: Have you at some point merged the other feature branch into master and then created the second feature branch from master (substitute master with the main branch which you use).

Answer (score 2):

Git's concept of branches-and-commits is very different from most other version control systems, even distributed ones like Mercurial.  If you are expecting that kind of behavior, you will be startled by Git's.

In most VCSes, when you make a commit, you make it *on a branch*, and from then on, that commit is *on that branch*.  That seems obvious.  It's not what Git does.

In Git, when you make a commit, you can be on a branch, or not on *any* branch at all (which Git calls a "detached HEAD").  The commit goes into the repository as usual.  If you *are* on a branch, then—by Git's definition of "on a branch"—the branch *name*, such as `master`, identifies the current commit (`HEAD` or `@`), which is necessarily the *tip commit* of that branch:

```
...--E--F--G   <-- master
```

(where each letter stands for some commit hash ID).  The new commit you make becomes the new tip of `master` and the name `master` gets changed to point to the new commit:

```
...--E--F--G--H   <-- master
```

You are still `on branch master`, as Git calls it, but now `master` names commit `H`.

The name itself, though, means little.  You can make Git re-point `master` to, say, commit `F`.  Commits `G` and `H` are no longer on `master` at all!  They're still *in the repository*, but no longer *part of the branch*:

```
...--E--F   <-- master
         \
          G--H
```

They do need to have *some* name (branch or tag name) by which they can be found, or they will eventually be garbage-collected.

The same goes for merges, though: once there is a *merge commit* that makes some other commits reachable, *all* of those commits are on the branch.  For instance, if we start instead with:

```
...--E--F--G   <-- master
      \
       H--I--J   <-- develop
```

and then merge `develop` into `master`, we get a new *merge commit* that links back to both commits `G` and `J`:

```
...--E--F--G---K   <-- master
      \       /
       H--I--J   <-- develop
```

Now all three of the previously-`develop`-only commits are on *both* branches.  Hence, running `git log` while on `master` will show you all of these commits.

(Note that commit `E`, and any earlier ones, is *also* on both branches, and was even before the merge.  Commits `F`, `G`, and `K` are *not* on `develop` now, but if the name `develop` is changed to point to `K`, they *will be* on `develop` at that point.)

You may wish to view the commit logs *with* a representation of the commit graph, e.g., `git log --oneline --graph` or `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph`.  (Or, most graphical viewers and GUIs try to draw some of the commit graph, with varying degrees of success if the graph is complex.)

Comment: You seem to be saying I merged the two feature branches, which I don't think I did (maybe I did).  I am going to test this behavior in a fresh repo and see it for myself.  Thanks for your explanatory answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create [orphan](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout---orphanltnewbranchgt) branch to avoid history from the branch it's created, it's like a `git init` which has no history ***even from master branch***:

```
git checkout feature
git checkout --orphan new-feature
git commit -m "new feature with no history"
```

Comment: I'm fine to do that but is the behavior I got really intended and I can't imagine everyone creates these orphans...

Comment: Also if it has no history will it jive with the remote master?

Comment: I mean I need to push this back to the origin, so if there is no history, will it work as any other branch would?  I basically want `git log` to show the last commit in master.  Maybe `checkout master` first?  Can't believe this is required.  Thought each branch would be more independent -- I've got to be missing something.

Comment: And how git places commit messages from a branch I'm not on and not master just boggles my mind.

Comment: will it work as any other branch would? - Yes, when you do `git push origin new-feature`, it creates a new branch in remote with all the commits taken from branch from which `new-feature` is created.